# How can I select two tables in mysql using join based on the input given by the user

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables. One is with user details and other is a table with some offer details. Both the tables have user ID as the primary key. I want to access all the details from both tables based on the ID provided by the user. How can I do that?
User table:-

```
---------------------------------------------
id    name    email    password    acc_conf
----------------------------------------------
```

Offer table:-

```
----------------------------------------------
id    user_id    offer_code    quantity
----------------------------------------------
```

script:-

```
<?php
     $id = $_POST['id'];
?>
```

Comment: First of all, a table of "user details" would *normally* have user ID as the *primary key*—what is the parent of the foreign relationship in this case?  As to your actual question, you're either going to want to `JOIN` the tables or make separate queries... depending on exactly what you're trying to accomplish (which certainly isn't clear from your question!).

Comment: Are you asking how to write a query that will do this? If so, you'll need to edit the question to provide more information about your tables and the output you're trying to get.

Comment: what are the common columns between the 2? is it `id` with `id` or `id` with `user_id`?

Comment: So sorry I meant primary key but I mentioned foreign key there

Comment: @Webeng Its 'id' with 'user_id'

Comment: @AshirogiMuto careful though, you might be open to sql injection attacks if you leave your code as stands. My answer also included how to protect yourself against them by using prepared statements and parameter binding. Let me know if that worked for you.

Comment: @Webeng I am learning prepared statements for that

Comment: @AshirogiMuto cool, it is the recommended method. oh and I edited my answer just slightly again. The prepared statement should be done with binding your parameters in order for the hack prevention to actually work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as follows:

```
$sql = "SELECT a.id AS user_id, a.name, a.email, a.password, a.acc_conf,
b.id AS offer_id, b.offer_code, b.quantity 
FROM user_table AS a, offer_table AS b
WHERE a.id = b.user_id AND a.id = {$id}";
```

**WARNING!:** If your using your above code as it stands, you are wide open to SQL Injection. The previous answer was just a proof of concept that the code would provide the right results, however I recommend you prepare the statement and  bind your parameters like so:

```
$sql = "SELECT a.id AS user_id, a.name, a.email, a.password, a.acc_conf,
b.id AS offer_id, b.offer_code, b.quantity 
FROM user_table AS a, offer_table AS b
WHERE a.id = b.user_id AND a.id = :id";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->execute();
```

I used the names `user_table` and `offer_table`. I wasn't sure if you actually had spaces between the names you places in your question. If you actually did have spaces, just replace the names in my code with `'user table'` and `'offer table'`. When you have spaces in columns and tables, quotations are necessary for SQL to understand those are spaces and not other commands in the SQL statement.

---

EDITED: In order to obtain the values you got from the execution of the query, you could use the following code:

```
$rows=$stmt->fetchAll();//now you have a multidimentional array called
                        //$rows with the information inside

print_r($rows);//echoing the information out
```

Comment: But how do I provide the value for id. It is coming from the user

Comment: @AshirogiMuto the `a.id` is obtaining the `id` from user because in the above example, `a` is `user_table`: `FROM user_table AS a`. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: @AshirogiMuto I edited my answer and named `a.id AS user_id` so the resulting table will have it under a column called `user_id`. Let me know if that was what you were looking for.

Comment: I have edited  my question. I want to fetch the data based on $id  given by the user

Comment: @Webeng : Are you mean `id` is the parameter? If so you need to add where clause as `WHERE a.id = ?`

Comment: @Webeng If you are suggesting a full OUTER join, mysql does not support them, nor the word FULL; if you are suggesting an INNER JOIN, using that wording is rather unconventional/misleading.

Comment: @AshirogiMuto no problem dude, glad I could help :)

Comment: How can I echo the values on executing the query?

Comment: @AshirogiMuto You would have to preform a `fetchAll()`, ill update my answer, 1 sec

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM user INNER JOIN user ON offer.user_id=user.id WHERE user.id=$id";
```

P.S.: Sanitize the input before executing your query otherwise it is vulnerable to SQL injections.